# Is the twelfth doctor based on Dr House?

Tags: doctor-who, character-similarity

Both characters appear to be of similar age. Yes, the Doctor is extremely old, but he looks like he's about the same age as Dr House.

Both seem more interested in solving the puzzle at hand rather than the peoples' feelings involved. Both are extraordinarily brilliant. Is the twelfth doctor based on (or influenced by) Dr House?

Comment: Oh Christ, I hope not. Doctor Who is not a boring medical procedural.

Comment: It's possible. There's certainly a trend of having the main character be smart and talented, yet very abrupt/rude: Sheldon, Sherlock, 12th Doctor, etc.

Comment: Timeline-wise, the Doctor with his general character attributes (talented yet sometimes unfriendly) predate House M.D. by more than 40 years.

Comment: I heard that [House was based on Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_House#Parallels_to_Sherlock_Holmes), by the way.

Comment: Hugh Laurie would be an AMAZING 13th or 14th Doctor. And he's British.

Comment: Here's a *Sherlock* reference in *House* too: [look at the address](https://scontent.fsnc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpl1/v/t1.0-9/10353115_707115862675441_2721808066896688267_n.jpg?oh=2eebfaeaaf4845ad46bf3b1c1ba8cd4b&oe=5735C0AD).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm confident that if Moffat was asked if he had based the twelfth doctor on Dr House, he would refute it emphatically. However, if Moffat were asked about the similarities in character traits I'm sure he would also see some common ground as you have.

Mr Lister's comment that he "I heard that House was based on Sherlock Holmes" is very interesting as we have seen the edges of the Doctor and Sherlock bleed into each over this series and Moffat writes for both characters and is a big fan of Conan Doyle. A whole sequence in "Heaven Sent" deconstructed the Doctor's thinking and actions in order to calculate acceleration due to local gravity (letting the eyepiece fall) and distance to whatever was below the window (throw bench, listen, count, hear splash etc.).

> In [an interview in the Radio Times](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/2015-12-02/steven-moffat-talks-ratings-misogyny-casting-missy-ashildrs-end-game-the-next-companion-and-leaving-doctor-who), Moffat says that "Doyle told
>   us how to do it. His cleverness was laid out for us 100 years ago.
>   Those deductions are hell. They’re very hard to write but as a
>   demonstrated intellectual skill, it’s pretty unstoppable. Doyle’s
>   first point about detectives was: you can’t just say they’re clever,
>   they’ve got to be clever. Every episode we try to have a new cool
>   deduction that makes sense. Now, if you deconstruct most of them,
>   Sherlock has a lucky knack of always guessing right, but let’s leave
>   that aside, it’s the deductions that make him clever. Very often in
>   the stories we tell of Sherlock are the days he fails or gets too
>   emotional, because the most dramatic tale to tell about a clever man
>   is that being clever isn’t enough."

If Mr Lister's source is correct, and I'm sure it will be, neither one is based on the other but both House and the twelfth incarnation Doctor do appear to share a common ancestor.